# Chrome Extension script won't execute after injection

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I researched this here at StackOverflow and either I did not come across the answer or I didn't understand the answer.

I am injecting a script that will toggle the header on a piece of cloud software. Trying to free up some screen real estate.

When I try to execute my script by clicking on the button, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: toggle is not defined
at HTMLInputElement.onclick
```

Which is odd since I define toggle just above the button. When I hard code the script into the page (as a saved HTML file)

Here are my files starting with the

**manifest.json**

```
    {
  "name": "Injector",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Injecting stuff",
  "homepage_url": "http://verdevalley.ihostfull.com",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Inject!"
  },
    "web_accessible_resources": ["script.js"],
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "file://*",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
// listen for our browerAction to be clicked
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    // for the current tab, inject the "inject.js" file & execute it
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
        file: 'inject.js'
    });
});
```

**inject.js**

```
(function() {
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.position = 'fixed';
div.style.zIndex="1004";
div.innerHTML = '<script id="custom">function toggle(){let x = document.getElementById("fixedTop");if (x.style.display === "none") {x.style.display = "block";} else {x.style.display = "none";}}</script><input type=button value=toggle onclick=toggle  float="left">';
document.body.appendChild(div);
document.getElementById('navbar').appendChild(div);

})();
```

If needed I can provide an HTML file on which to run this script, but I have a feeling it won't be necessary.